# Automatic horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, swift3

What should I do to **automatically horizontal scroll** just like app store does?

There will be bunch of images. These images with some delay come to the screen and move out and this gets repeated infinitely, like app store.

Comment: check https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102

https://github.com/terenceLuffy/AppStoreStyleHorizontalScrollView

Comment: It's just a scrolling  but what I'm looking for is "automatic" scrolling. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I am sorry .i missed auto scroll somehow..Have you checked  iCarousel library?It has autoScroll property where you can set it true & enable scroll in horizontal https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Thanks Ellen. I'm looking at that library as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

https://github.com/evgenyneu/Auk

Add this to your pod file

```
   pod 'Auk', '~> 7.0'
```

run pod install

```
  import UIKit
  struct DemoConstants {



 static let button = DemoConstantsButton()
 static let initialImage = (
    fileName: "slider1.jpg",
    description: " demo"
)
static let localImages = [
    (
        fileName: "image1.jpg",
        description: "Hotel Nirvana"
    ),
    (
        fileName: "image2.jpg",
        description: "Hotel Nirvana"
    ),
    (
        fileName: "image3.jpg",
        description: "demo2"
    ),
    (
        fileName: "image4.jpg",
        description: "demo3"
    ),

    (
        fileName: "image5.jpg",
        description: "demo4"
    ),
    (
        fileName: "image6.jpg",
        description: "demo5"
    )]
    }


    struct DemoConstantsButton {
    let borderWidth: CGFloat = 2
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20
    let borderColor = UIColor.white
    }
```

In your viewcontroller

```
   import Auk
```

add delegate  UIScrollViewDelegate

```
    class yourViewController: UIViewController ,UIScrollViewDelegate
```

take a UIScrollView and make a outlet

```
           @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

in viewDidLoad

```
      scrollView.delegate = self
        for localImage in DemoConstants.localImages {


        if let image = UIImage(named: localImage.fileName) {
            scrollView.auk.show(image: image)
      }}





    let pageIndex = scrollView.auk.currentPageIndex
    print(pageIndex!)



    scrollView.auk.settings.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    scrollView.auk.settings.pagingEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.auk.settings.pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    scrollView.auk.startAutoScroll(delaySeconds: 3)
    scrollView.auk.scrollToPage(atIndex: 2, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: so can you please click the right tick button to verify that my solution solved you problem it would be highly appreciated